# Django access from outside VMWARE (Public access)

Tags: django, python-3.x, networking, firewall

I'm using Django 3.0.5 under Kalilinux2020.1 launched from a virtual machine on VMWARE ESXI.
I want to make my project public but it's not working.

I modified the settings.py and add :
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

The django server is launched using 
`pyhton3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`

I allowed the port 8080 in the firewall using 
`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp`

and I forwarded the port 8080 in the router

P.S: I can access to my server from the other machines in the VMWare (LAN) but i can't get access from outside.
Anyone has faced this problem?

Comment: I changed the port in router to forward 9001 and it's working.
thank you dears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out the solution,

I changed the port to be forwarded from 8080 to 9001 and it works like charm now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The network adapter in your VM, it should be either Brigde or NAT either way it can't be accessible other hosts